# uiautomator : Error while creating temporary file to save snapshot

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator, appium-android

When i try to capture element in uiautomator Viewer and i got erorr message like screenshot below :

> Error while creating temporary file to save snapshot: null
>
> PS: i'm using linux mint 19 with JDK V8.

[image]

Comment: disconnect and connect the device again. It should work

Comment: @Vinod No, it's not . i already try .

Comment: have you captured the same screen successfully before? If not, if you are trying for the first time then check the source code xml file of these screen. There could be some error in the xml formatting.

Comment: my computer just set up linux mint. and i had this problems. before i can capture as normal while i'm using windows